# How to save a image in flutter? Not able to use .copy method. in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have tried the following code and facing issues with it. .copy method seems not working for the updated flutter version.

```
Future getImage() async {
        var image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        var appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final String appDirPath = appDir.path;
        var fileName = provider.basename(image.path);
        setState(() {
          var _storedImage = image;
        });
        var localImage = await image.copy('$appDir/$fileName');
        data.sp.setString('backgroundPath', localImage.path);
        setState(() {
          _background = Image.file(File(localImage.path), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
        });
      }
```

Comment: do you get a specific error message or did you just encounter that no file was saved?

Answer (score 2):

`Future<PickedFile> getImage` return `PickedFile` not `File`

```
 PickedFile image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

You can use `File(image.path).copy`

```
var localImage = await File(image.path).copy('$appDir/$fileName');
```

Comment: try this one : final savedImage =
        await File(imageFile.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');